# Android function to AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I am trying to create an AsyncTask for following function:

```
private void updateStreamImageRequest() {
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 2000) {
        @Override
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             imageRequest();
         }
         @Override
         public void onFinish() {
             countDownTimer.start();
         }
     };
}
```

I do not have much knowledge in AsyncTaskand I am struggling to make it work. The AsyncTask shall continueally run a get request.
So far I have done this so far but it does not work:

```
public void getImgAsync() {
    new requestAsyncTask();
}

public class requestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 2000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                API_StreamImage_Request();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                countDownTimer.start();
            }
        };
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve from your code

Comment: I want to continueally run a get request to get data

Comment: Every 10 seconds? so then you want the getting data part from Asynctask right?

Comment: @kapsym yes, I want to run in my AsyncTask every 10 seconds

Comment: You forgot to call .execute() after calling asyncTask.

Comment: @junikear check my answer below and it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So do it this way -

Create your Countdown timer that runs for 10 seconds. So it will finish after 10 seconds. Then in finish method call your Asynctask to fetch in background.

```
countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 5000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            new requestAsyncTask().execute();
        }
};
countDownTimer.start();


class requestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countDownTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        API_StreamImage_Request();
        return null;
    }
}
```

You might have to create a global variable of your countdown timer so that you can access it inside your asynctask class. Or you can even pass it as well if you want.

Comment: Hi thanks I get an error: doInBackground() misses a return statement

Comment: @junikear Added. Also notice modified the Asynctask declaration to pass String in 3rd parameter. If you have all as Void you can just return nil

Comment: Updated my code as well. Plus we were doing cancellation on pre execute which ideally should be done only when your fetch request is complete hence moved it to postExecute. I though i had typed post but when checked again it was pre. My bad

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `Handler` for this.

```
private int mInterval = 10000;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

Runnable requestCaller = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            new requestAsyncTask().execute();
        } finally {
            mHandler.postDelayed(requestCaller, mInterval);
        }
    }
};
```

Or a `Timer`

```
 new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new requestAsyncTask().execute();
        }
    },0, 10000);
```